# Java: Could not find the main class. Program will exit

Tags: java, jvm, manifest

Works on my PC. Doesn't work on the 2 others I tried: they get the entitled error.

Manifest.txt:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: core.Initiator
```

^ extra line at the end.

Hierarchy:

```
Project.jar
    core
        Initiator
        ...
    images
        ...
    META-INF
        MANIFEST.MF
```

CreateJar.bat:

```
cd bin
jar cvfm ..\Project.jar ..\Manifest.txt *
pause
```

Run.bat:

```
@echo off
start javaw -jar Project.jar
```

Comment: Can you specify which system (details like OS, OS version, 32/64 bit etc.) it ran successfully and on which did not?

Comment: Ran on win7 home premium 64bit.
Didn't run on Vista home basic 32bit, another win7 home 64bit.

Comment: What happens if you move your jar to your desktop and try to run it that way?

Comment: Oh darn. Still ran but the program can't find images now (they don't render) O.o...

Comment: Can you dump the output of error and command used, for both all the machines?

Comment: output of error? It gives a popup? Or do you mean something else? All the computers had that same .jar file and that same Run.bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computers with the error needed to update their JDK.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments in the actual question. This could be because of the relative paths that you are using.

Also, does your jar file contain the images or is it just lying somewhere in the workspace? This would again suggest that the relative paths may be wrong.

Comment: fixed the images... forgot how to add them. They should have been in the same location as the .jar file instead of being inside the .jar. Works off of the desktop/whichever folder fully now (for this PC anyways). Don't know exactly what you mean by "because of the relatives paths". The paths are indeed relative but they're accurate, no..?